# containerd cleanup of unused images resulted in no ability to schedule newer pods on the node in aws eks 1.24 (401 Unauthorized)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, containerd

I have removed unused images from the eks managed node:

```bash
VERSION="v1.24.0"
wget https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/cri-tools/releases/download/$VERSION/crictl-$VERSION-linux-amd64.tar.gz
sudo tar zxvf crictl-$VERSION-linux-amd64.tar.gz -C /usr/local/bin
rm -f crictl-$VERSION-linux-amd64.tar.gz

crictl rmi --prune
...
E0315 20:34:44.722882    3708 remote_image.go:266] "RemoveImage from image service failed" err="rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = context deadline exceeded" image="sha256:cb6ad2a0d0b8738bf49d40f30fc761ad056f3a7d92485bab1189e6479e17b825"
E0315 20:34:46.724693    3708 remote_image.go:266] "RemoveImage from image service failed" err="rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to delete image reference \"sha256:76459b0d1fe351120c2e859d78103f71e0d2d8fb8e88d763fc9fe245b594a752\" for \"sha256:76459b0d1fe351120c2e859d78103f71e0d2d8fb8e88d763fc9fe245b594a752\": context deadline exceeded: unknown" image="sha256:76459b0d1fe351120c2e859d78103f71e0d2d8fb8e88d763fc9fe245b594a752"
E0315 20:34:48.726699    3708 remote_image.go:266] "RemoveImage from image service failed" err="rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = context deadline exceeded" image="sha256:2930c411b7f87ff4e456b5794af3acc8878b48efd28f32c2fbf249d3aa89a34f"
E0315 20:34:50.729243    3708 remote_image.go:266] "RemoveImage from image service failed" err="rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = context deadline exceeded" image="sha256:c1858046ea8d53658900683f171a72556e1ae5517b69c3d70a5c94db7efdcdde"
E0315 20:34:52.730840    3708 remote_image.go:266] "RemoveImage from image service failed" err="rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = context deadline exceeded" image="sha256:1d88327b479f9ae8ca6acbde498d863ee5c667cdc6214b8f247546b138c424de"
E0315 20:34:54.731837    3708 remote_image.go:266] "RemoveImage from image service failed" err="rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = context deadline exceeded" image="sha256:959507aa163065cc9f94593e0aa510eb9a2ebe22e08aa9b4bb9db505164520c0"
E0315 20:34:56.733725    3708 remote_image.go:266] "RemoveImage from image service failed" err="rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = context deadline exceeded" image="sha256:917735e204cc630eb4b987348d79fdc4695427c831c5cd43899e6601a41e98d4"
E0315 20:34:58.737552    3708 remote_image.go:266] "RemoveImage from image service failed" err="rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = context deadline exceeded" image="sha256:9b675f1876698c455cb61b9f76fd0cd7cd21a01ecfef4224d2b239f65f32fd48"
E0315 20:35:00.739194    3708 remote_image.go:266] "RemoveImage from image service failed" err="rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = context deadline exceeded" image="sha256:dc9a592e595f623ed2c6407af528dc55f58c5d5d734aa18330a2dc53aa4b4683"
E0315 20:35:02.741586    3708 remote_image.go:266] "RemoveImage from image service failed" err="rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = context deadline exceeded" image="sha256:290bb234ad7af6756275c194e72a9587d942a11337c878cba5831a778f9e6bf5"
[root@ip-10-110-9-54 ~]# exit
logout

...
```

After that any new pods that are scheduled on that node are failed to be started with the following error:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason                  Age                   From               Message
  ----     ------                  ----                  ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled               18m                   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned pb/pb-migration-after-db-dump-v1-27981870-6rlgm to ip-10-110-2-12.us-west-2.compute.internal
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  3m24s (x71 over 18m)  kubelet            Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to get sandbox image "602401143452.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/eks/pause:3.5": failed to pull image "602401143452.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/eks/pause:3.5": failed to pull and unpack image "602401143452.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/eks/pause:3.5": failed to resolve reference "602401143452.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/eks/pause:3.5": pulling from host 602401143452.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com failed with status code [manifests 3.5]: 401 Unauthorized
```